# Required help in regex

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a regex that validate value 10, 10GB.....
I want to correct it to something like it should not take value 10.
regex : "^\d+(\.\d\d?)?\s*(B|[KMGTP]B|%)?$"

regards
NewDev

Comment: Please try to explain more clearly what you want you want to match with your regular expression.

Comment: this regular expression validate value 10, which i do not want it to validate

Comment: What *do* you want to match? There's literally a limitless number of regexps that will not validate "10". Are you trying to only match if it contains a unit (the "GB" in your question)?

Answer (score 1):

Just get rid of the ? after the (B|[KMGTP]B|%) bit and it'll work as intended.  Also might want to change the * after \s to ? so it doesn't match `"10_____B"`.  (where _ is space)

```
"^\d+(\.\d\d?)?\s?(B|[KMGTP]B|%)$"
```

Comment: I think your regex still matches "10 B" and I think he wants it to, but the \s* implies that he wants to allow any number of spaces after the number

Comment: Yes, that's why I said "might want to".  I just find it a bit odd to match an endless number of spaces between the number and the unit.

Comment: I see. I posted my comment before your example string had multiple spaces.

Comment: Hi I want that regex to validate on values like 10B, 10GB, 10KB, 10MB,10%, 10TP